# Disable Share and Follow button

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, social

I followed the steps below to disable the "share" and "follow" buttons in Sharepoint:

**Disable Share Button**

1. Settings > Site Settings > User and Permission : Site Permission
2. Click Access request Settings  > Uncheck allow accesst request

**Disable Follow button**

1. Settings > Site Settings > Site Actions : Manage Site Features
2. Deactivate feature : Following Content

Is there also a way to do this with a PowerShell script?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> This script goes through the hierarchy and disables the Following Content feature in every WebSite. You get an error message for every site where the feature is not active or missing. This can be ignored

```
$w = Get-SPWeb http://MySharePointURL | ForEach{ $_.URL }
Get-SPFeature -Web $w |%{ Disable-SPFeature -Identity "FollowingContent" -URL $w -Confirm:$false}
```

> This script disables the “Allow access request” setting under Site Settings -> Site Permissions -> Allow access request for all Sites and SubSites und the configured URL

```
$Webapp = Get-SPWebApplication "http://MySharePointURL"
ForEach ($site in $webapp.Sites)
{ForEach ($web in $site.AllWebs | where {$_.RequestAccessEnabled -and $_.Permissions.Inherited -eq $false})
{$web.RequestAccessEmail=""
write-host $web.Title, $web.URL updated}}
```

Source: [Deactivate social feature MySite, Newsfeed, OneDrive, Sync, Share & Follow in SharePoint 2013](http://www.sharepointtalk.net/2014/10/deactivate-social-feature-mysite.html)

Comment: Can these share buttons be hidden only in 1 Document Library? I thought of applying CSS in this particular page not sure if thats correct approach.

Comment: @AsadRefai AFAIK They can be hidden by CSS or removed by JavaScript. I think it's an OK approach instead of disabling for the whole tenant.

Comment: i need to disables the “Allow access request” in Shrarepoint 2019 , unfortunately this script dsenot work, any idea please

Comment: @ImenTurki Sorry, I have no clue

Answer (score 2):

Disable Below Feature :

```
Disable-SPFeature -Identity "FollowingContent" -Url http:/sp/site/web
```

Comment: Please provide more information to your answer.

Comment: It's a Powerless command to write in share point management shell

Comment: You mean Powerful or PowerShell? :)

Comment: Power shall command Using  sharepoint management shall.